# Can't import cv2 in Python 2.7 linux

Tags: linux, python-2.7, opencv

I'm trying to get OpenDroneMap to run on my linux mint machine.  I've been working my way through a number of problems in the current release's dependency chain.

At the moment, I'm stumped on getting the OpenCV module, cv2 to import.

OpenCV is required by an OpenDroneMap dependency, OpenSfM and it's one of the OpenSfM py files that tries to import the module cv2.

Anyway, running OpenDroneMap generates the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "~/OpenDroneMap/src/OpenSfM/bin/opensfm", line 10, in <module>
from opensfm import commands
File "~/OpenDroneMap/src/OpenSfM/opensfm/commands/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
import extract_metadata
File "~/OpenDroneMap/src/OpenSfM/opensfm/commands/extract_metadata.py", line 5, in <module>
from opensfm import dataset
File "~/OpenDroneMap/src/OpenSfM/opensfm/dataset.py", line 12, in <module>
import cv2
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_cv2)
b

quitting cause: 
    PYTHONPATH=~/OpenDroneMap/lib/python2.7/dist-packages "~/OpenDroneMap/src/OpenSfM/bin/run_all" opensfm
returned with code 256.
```

From what I can tell, the import error cause typically suggests that the cv2 module was not found.  I've ensured that cv2.so does exist in the path specified, as well as the usr/lib/python27/dist-packages path, where it seems to me it should really be looking...

In any case, I was hoping someone might be able to give me some direction on what to try next.

Comment: Please try `import cv2` on the prompt and check if it throws an error. If it does, then it is a problem with your OpenCV installation.

Comment: Tried that with Python 2.7.  No error.

Comment: Then it is not the problem with the openCV installation. I am not familiar with the package that you have said in the question. Please check if you have installed it correctly. OpenCV  installation is fine.